# Ionic3| Facing with an issue when add InAppBrowser into providers

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I need open a link into my Ionic-3 project and when I google it I saw InAppBrowser Plugin.

Actually there is only one picture in this link so If you know any other method for get it or show directly this picture it is can be enough for me.

I done all of it like what documentary done.
The Documentary which is I used for : https://blog.paulhalliday.io/ionic-3-integrating-inappbrowser-plugin/

Step-1: I installed `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

Step-2: I installed as well `npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser --save`

And there was no error in Command Line(Terminal)

Step-3: I imported the plugin into *app.module.ts* `import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';`
And there was no error in code editor

!!! Step-4: When I tried to add InAppBrowser  into providers part I faced an error like picture which below
[image: This is the picture of error]
If you can not see : http://prntscr.com/mc964l link is here.

Why that error happened I do not get it.

Can anybody help me about this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

**Ionic 3:**

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser@4
```

**You must append version 4 to the package name after the @ character (version 5.x is not compatible with Ionic 3):**

Then, add to Provider:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    InAppBrowser 
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/in-app-browser/

**Ionic 4:**

For Angular, the import path should end with **/ngx**

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
```

Then, add to Provider:

```
// app.module.ts
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    InAppBrowser 
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native#angular

Comment: You didn't test your code. `@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx` is not a valid module.

Comment: @ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx is valid only in Ionic 4

You are installing the default version of the plugin (v5.x) is not compatible with Ionic 3, you need downgrade to version 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there are people still facing this issue after upgrading to Angular 11 + I found out that the problem is with the ivy.

The import should look like this:

`import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/__ivy_ngcc__/ngx';`